# Textarea form submit without refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Textarea isn't submitting the form with out refresh

Code for submission of form without refresh

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#post_reply").click(function(event) {
        $.post( '../services/leave_comment.php', $("#open_status").serialize(),  
        function( data ) 
        if(data.split("::")[1]==true){
            $("#data_status").html("Commented Successfully..");     
            $("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);               document.getElementById('_comment').value='';  
            $('#_comment').html("");
            location.reload();
        }else if(data.split("::")[1]==false){
            $("#data_status").html("Error occured in Comment Submission.. Try Again..");                +       
        $("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);  
        }

    }  
);  
});
```

Code for shift+enter for new line and enter for submit the form

```
function getCaret(el) {
    if (el.selectionStart) {
        return el.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        var re = el.createTextRange(),
        rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
$('.commenttextarea').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
        var content = this.value;
        var caret = getCaret(this);
        this.value = content.substring(0, caret) + "\n" + content.substring(caret, content.length - 1);
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.commentform').submit();
    }
});
```

Here is the **[Fiddle!!](http://jsfiddle.net/u4Ray/1/)**

Now the problem is, its refreshing after submit the form
and sometimes enter key isn't working as it should.

Detailed explanation appreciated.

Comment: In fiddle where .commenttextarea and .commentform elements? I can see post_reply textbox only Anyhow you can try this event.preventDefault(); and any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `event.preventDefault()` will help you for without page refresh we can submit. When ever you make ajax inside event handler use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent from page refresh.

```
  (document).ready(function(){$("#post_reply").click(function(event) {

   event.preventDefault(); //NOTE HERE

 $.post( '../services/leave_comment.php', $("#open_status").serialize(),  
          function( data ) 
   if(data.split("::")[1]==true){
$("#data_status").html("Commented Successfully..");     
$("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);               document.getElementById('_comment').value='';  
    $('#_comment').html("");
    location.reload();
    }else if(data.split("::")[1]==false){
        $("#data_status").html("Error occured in Comment Submission.. Try Again..");                +       
    $("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);  
    }

          }  
        );  
      });
```

Place add following code.

```
$(".commentform").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```